# Woocommerce page numbering

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with woocommerce. I am browsing through products, which are in store, but I don't see any page numbers, there are about 400 products and no pages.

Maybe somebody has faced with similar problem? Or this is a problem with theme?

Woocommerce version: 2.1.12 
Wordpress version: 3.9.1

Comment: I think WooCommerce has pagination (page numbers) by default on it's archives. Revert to a default theme such as Twenty Fourteen to confirm that your theme has disabled this feature.

Comment: I changed to default theme and it still doesn't show page numbers.

Comment: It is definitely enabled by default. It is added to the `woocommerce_after_shop_loop` hook in `wc_template_hooks.php` `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10 );` Also, verify that you don't have any plugins filtering `woocommerce_pagination_args` in unexpected way or any plugins messing with the query as if the query's max number of pages is <=1 pagination will never show. Basically, also disable plugins and then re-enable them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a conflict here with your theme or another plugin. It was mentioned earlier that you've tried switching to a default theme. You might have a conflicting plugin at this point. I also **highly** recommend updating WooCommerce and WordPress to the latest version and try testing again. There's been a number of security fixes from both of them.